# How to use addActionMessage without extending ActionSupport

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, annotations

I am using @Action to define my action class, but to use `addActionMessage` I have to extend `ActionSupport` class.

As my controller is extending an abstract class I cant extend `ActionSupport` class.
What should I do to use `addActionMessage` without extending `ActionSupport`.

```java
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;

@Action
public class MyClass extends AbstractOtherClass implements ModelDriven {
      ....
    public String Messages(){
       addActionMessage("g");  << cannot find symbol error 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to extend ActionSupport with your AbstractOtherClass?

Comment: And we've an answer here :)

Comment: @AleksandrM, please read the question again

Comment: @DanielMorgan: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

This exposes one of the issues with inheritance; you must make sure you're extending classes at the right point in the hierarchy. Here the comment is correct (and should probably be an answer): it's the abstract base class that should be extending `ActionSupport`.

That said, whether or not that's the *best* approach is subject to some debate. The class hierarchy of S2 means that it's certainly the *easiest* approach, but you might also be able to implement the appropriate interface and use existing S2 functionality to achieve the same result, albeit with more effort.

S2 (correctly) claims that actions can be POJOs, but the truth is that you lose a *lot* of S2 functionality if you do so. Actions should be viewed as the interface between the client (usually the browser) and the Code That Actually Gets Stuff Done. Tying the web layer to the web framework isn't really an issue: you may lose a tiny amount of flexibility, but that flexibility should be encoded elsewhere and *used* by the web layer.

Comment: does that mean the only way is : MyClass should extend ActionSupport and I need to  create another class say A to extend abstracOtherClass ? and access that A class from Action ?

Comment: @DanielMorgan No, it means you need to decide which route expresses your intent the best.

Comment: lets say I have a class called person and two classes are inheriting person class called personA and personB each with their additional attributes. So I need to have two different controllers one for each class. Both Controllers should extend the abstract class to avoid of recoding, whats your idea ? which route is better?

Comment: @DanielMorgan Depends. Rhetorical questions: what action functionality is shared? Which functionality is tied specifically to each user type? Would implementing ModelDriven or directly exposing each user type be sufficient? It's impossible to give meaningful advice without details, and even then, it may come down to a matter of preference, or be obvious.